# What's a good beer to have with curry?

Tags: pairing

This question might still be too broad, as there are different styles of curry. But let's say a lamb korma.

Would it the spicyness change the selection? - Ie a tasty, but not spicy curry, vs a burn your mouth curry.

Comment: I think some good beers would be Apricot Ale, ShockTop, Stella Artois, Blue Moon, and India Pale Ale

Answer (score 7):

In general, the rule of thumb for spicy or intensely flavorful foods is that you want hop-forward beers. The high bitterness of something like an IPA will have a slight numbing effect on your palate, cutting the intensity of spicy foods and allowing you to appreciate the complexity of a dish more than you could if you were simply overwhelmed by capsaicin.

Comment: I could see this working, or if not hop-forward something with a lighter, refreshing, and crisp body, like a plain lager or pilsner.